# Python: how to filter the points only in a specific boundary using geopandas?

Tags: python, shapefile, geopandas

I have a shapefile with some points.

```
import geopandas as gpd
from geopandas.tools import sjoin
import osmnx as ox

myShape = gpd.read_file('myShape.shp')
myShape.head(3)

geometry
0   POINT (-72.09513801999077 18.6526410972226)
1   POINT (-72.21044508038457 19.61039786418674)
2   POINT (-72.27903674995586 18.52939294725028)
```

Then I extracted a city from open street map and its boundaries. I want to keep only the points that are inside the city.

This is what I am doing:

```
city = ox.gdf_from_place('Paris', which_result=2)
city = gpd.GeoDataFrame(city)

myShapeTmp = myShape.copy()
for i in myShape.index:
    if (myShape['geometry'][i] in gdf['geometry']) == False:
        myShapeTmp = myShapeTmp.drop([i], axis=0)
```

But it takes forever. Is there a different way to do it?

Answer (score 4):

I solved in this way

```
myShape = gpd.read_file('myShape.shp')
myShape.head(3)

geometry
0   POINT (-72.09513801999077 18.6526410972226)
1   POINT (-72.21044508038457 19.61039786418674)
2   POINT (-72.27903674995586 18.52939294725028)


city = ox.gdf_from_place('Paris', which_result = 2)
city = gpd.GeoDataFrame(city)
boundary = city.ix[0].geometry
myShapeTmp = myShape[myShape.geometry.within(boundary)]
```

Comment: What is `school`?

Answer (score 0):

A different way of doing to get `points in polygon` can be like this:

Let's create a file `port_au_princ.csv` with the following content:

```
index,geometry
0,POINT(-72.09513801999077 18.6526410972226)
1,POINT(-72.21044508038457 19.61039786418674)
2,POINT(-72.27903674995586 18.52939294725028)
```

Here is the code that does all the necessary operations.

```
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd
from geopandas.tools import sjoin
import osmnx as ox
from shapely.wkt import loads

# get polygon of the city
city_pgon = ox.gdf_from_place('Port-au-Prince', which_result = 2)
# create a geoDataFrame out of it, set appropriate CRS
city_pgon = gpd.GeoDataFrame(city_pgon, crs={'init': 'epsg:4326'})
# read the file
pap = pd.read_csv('port_au_princ.csv', sep=',')
geometry = [loads(pt) for pt in pap['geometry']]  # prep geometry
# create geoDataFrame from `pap` dataframe
geo_pap = gpd.GeoDataFrame(pap, geometry=geometry, crs={'init': 'epsg:4326'})
pts_in_poly = gpd.sjoin(geo_pap, city_pgon, op='within', how='inner') # do spatial join

ax1 = city_pgon.plot()   # plot the polygon
geo_pap.plot(ax=ax1, color='red', zorder=5)         # plot red points
pts_in_poly.plot(ax=ax1, color='yellow', zorder=6)  # plot yellow point
```

The plot will be:

[image: point-in-poly]

Print out some information of `pts_in_poly` with this code:

```
print(pts_in_poly.index, pts_in_poly.geometry)
```

the output,

```
Int64Index([2], dtype='int64') 2    POINT (-72.27903674995586 18.52939294725028)
Name: geometry, dtype: object
```

Comment: note that doing geo*metric* operations on geo*graphic* data can lead to unexpected results

Comment: @PaulH Thanks. I'll be careful. This case is OK.